# Asp panel visible setting not changing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to change the visible setting of a panel with a button click. I need the second panel become visible when the button at the bottom of first panel is clicked.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphContent" runat="Server">
<asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="0"
        AllowSorting="True" CssClass="grid" Visible="true">
        <Columns>
            //gv1 columns here
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button ID="btnModAdd" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Ekle" OnClick="btnModAdd_Click">
    </asp:Button>
    <br />
    <div class="dataTables_paginate" id="example_info">
        <uc1:PagingControl ID="pcBottom" runat="server" PagingPosition="Top" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
<br />
<asp:Panel ID="pnl2" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <asp:GridView ID="gv2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="0"
        AllowSorting="True" CssClass="grid" Visible="true">
        <Columns>
            //gv2 columns here..
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

And this is C# code of the button, quite simple.

```
public void btnModAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnl2.Visible = true;
}
```

I can't understand what I'm missing to see here...

EDIT: Ok I noticed I missed to add the bind method to pageload. Noob mistake on my part but well, still learning :)

Comment: can you post `btnModAdd` html? and also your `Page_Load` event?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with panel visibility? Maybe the gridview is empty so the panel is visible but there's nothing inside it? If you set  *Visible="true"* in markup, is it visible then? And does it stay visible after you click *btnModAdd*?

Comment: did you debug and see if it is going to button click event. because there is nothing wrong in your code. and just for testing purpose try to give different background color to panel and try to see if it is visible on btn click event and there is typo on your gv2 grid `Visible="truee"` it should be `Visible="true"` an extra `e` in true.

Comment: please add some value in the second panel and then test .sometime gridview is empty and we think that it is not visible for us .